# Hide a div based on a select input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was helped with some code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/13/). I tweaked it to try and hide a whole div instead of an element. It was only a small tweak but I seem to have done something to stop it working.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="text-708" value="" class="wpcf7-validates-as-required" size="40">
<div id="added_fields">
    <select name="menu-168" class="wpcf7-validates-as-required">
        <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
        <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS

```
if ($("select[name='menu-168']").val() == "Commercial") {
    $("#added_fields").addClass("hidden");
}​
```

Would someone be kind enough to tell me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the check of the select value when it changes.

> I want to hide the input box not the select box im afraid

In that case you need to change the `#added_fields` selector. Try this:

```
$("select[name='menu-168']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Commercial") {
        $('#added_fields').addClass("hidden");
    }
    else {
        $('#added_fields').removeClass("hidden")
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/54/)

Comment: Ah! Sorry I put the div in the wrong place. I fixed it but the input box doesnt re-appear when "residential" is selected http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/37/

Comment: I would like it applied to the div though like this: http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/50/

Answer (score 1):

You `did not write the code on change event of select` and *your selected value at load is not commercial so your statement under if does not execute*.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/K9zGP/43/)**

```
$("select[name='menu-168']").change(function() {

    if ($("select[name='menu-168']").val() == "Commercial") {
        $("input[name=text-708]").addClass("hidden");
    }
    else
        $("input[name=text-708]").removeClass("hidden");
});​
```

Comment: I want to hide the input box not the select box im afraid

Comment: Updated my answer, have a look.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer, but now the input box doesnt reappear when the value of "residential" is selected

Comment: I want it applied to the div though please like this: http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/48/

Comment: Could not understant what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line

```
 $("#added_fields").addClass("hidden");
```

to

```
 $("#added_fields").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#added_fields").hide();
```

you can find more information here: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Updated: If you want to refer to the change event of your select you have to either fire your function in the onselectedindexchanged attribute of your select or add a change event on it via jQuery:

```
$("select[name='menu-168']").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Commercial") {
    $("#added_fields").hide();
  }
});
```

more info about change: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only executing once, on `$(document).ready();`. Wrap it in a `.change()` event handler.

```
$("select[name='menu-168']").change(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() == "Commercial") {
        $("#added_fields").addClass("hidden");
    }
});​
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/36/

**UPDATE:**

To make the text-input reappear in jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/46, use `.toggleClass()` instead:

```
$("select[name='menu-168']").change(function(e) {
    var isCommercial = $(this).val() == "Commercial";
    $("#added_fields").toggleClass("hidden", isCommercial);
});​
```

YAF: http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/71/

Comment: It doesnt re-appear when you select residential though http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/46/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("select[name='menu-168']").change(function() {

if ( $(this).val() == "Commercial") {
    $("#added_fields").hide();
}
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("select").change(function(){
if($("select option:selected").val() == "Commercial") 
$("input[name=text-708]").hide();
else
$("input[name=text-708]").show();   
});
```

​
​ [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/52/)

Comment: It doesnt re-appear though when you select residential http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/49/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `option:selected property` in the change event of the select list

```
$("select[name='menu-168']").bind("change",function(e){

    if ($("select[name='menu-168'] option:selected").val() == "Commercial") {
        $("#added_fields").hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: `option:selected` is not required. Getting the `val()` of a select will automatically return the value of the selected `option`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to "attach" to a event "hide".

So you can do this with `click()` (or `change()`) event like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/velthune/K9zGP/41/).

Answer (score 0):

hay yomiss to call the change event of the select box.
check this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/44/

```
 $("select[name='menu-168']").change(function(){
alert($(this).val());
if ($(this).val() == "Commercial") {
$("#added_fields").addClass("hidden");
}

});
```

Comment: It doesnt re-appear when you select residential though : http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/47/